# set variables to twig when redirect link?

Tags: php, symfony

i want to set a variable to twig when redirect link like when use the render methods :

```
return $this->render('socialBundle::index.html.twig',array(
                    'id' => $id
                ));
```

it will set the Id variable to twig : {{ id }}

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("tuto_animaux_voir", array(
                    'id' => $id
                )));
```

it will set the Id variable to the link :  xxxxx.com/Id , i want that it render this variable to twig  when redirect ...

sorry for this bad concept and language because i'm not england , and this is my first question in stackoverflow ,

wait for a reponse , thanks

Comment: You can't send data on the redirect. You can create another action which takes your `id` parameter and fetch `object` from database.

Comment: Which variable do you want to pass?

Comment: Could you describe your business logic please?

Comment: i want create a simple signup/login/logout site , i just want to show some alerts into the index when enter this link xxxxx.com/alert that's why i want redirect the link to the index and show the alert var ...

Comment: Check my answer, I think that's what you want.

Comment: where is your answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want to do, if you want to put a link in a twig template or just redirect from a controller according a condition. if you can give more details of what you want to do I think I can help you.

**UPDATE (solution)**

You could use "Forwarding to Another Controller" instead of using "Redirect" and from there to send the variables to the twig template

Comment: i just want to pass a variable to twig using redirect ?

Comment: You could use ["Forwarding to Another Controller"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller) instead of using "Redirect" and from there to send the variables to the twig template.

Answer (score 0):

In you case 'tuto_animaux_voir' is a route associated to controller action. Given id will be available as action parameter, so you can pass it like this:

```
public function fooAction($id)
{
    return $this->render(
        'socialBundle::foo.html.twig',
        ['id' => $id]
    )
}
```

You can also fetch data from database and pass them to the view.

If that's not what to you want to achieve, tell us why you want to use redirect, and what these two actions should do.

**Edit:**
If I understood your comment correctly, you want to implement flash messages, which are [already available in symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages).

Example in docs is simple and self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, I came to the following conclusion.

Assume that you have index action, with route `tuto_animaux_voir`. And route has one parameter `id`. It takes `id` as parameter and fetches alert from the database(we have alerts on the database). Also we have entity `Alert` with fields id(default), title.

...

```
public function indexAction($id){
  $alert = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager("AppBundle:Alert")->find($id);

  return $this->render("AppBundle:Post:index.html.twig", array(
     'alert' => $alert
  ));
}
```

In your template `index.html.twig` you can show your alert.

```
...
 {{ alert.title }}
...
```

If you want to redirect to the index action in the twig.

```
<a href="{{ path("tuto_animaux_voir", { 'id': alert_id })}}">Alert Title<a>
```

Also if you want render this action as partial.

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Alert:index',{'id': alert_id})) }}
```

I think my answer would be helpful for you.

Comment: nice , but this will not redirect the page it will show the id in the link , ... i just want to pass it without show it ..

Comment: Okay. Problem is that you can not totally describe your business logic.

Comment: do you understand it now ??

Comment: I think you want to implement your own bicycle.